# Fill selected cell with text

Tags: excel, button, vba

How do I fill the currently selected cell with predetermined and formatted text?

For example if cell `A1` is highlighted, if I click a button named `Greetings`, it'll fill cell `A1` with text `"Hello"` in bold, if I click a button named `Food`, it'll fill cell `A1` with `bread (linebreak) ham (linebreak) mayo` in red.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In General SO is not a code for me site.  Please post, in your original post, what you have tried and what it is doing or not doing that is undesirable.  As to the answer to your only question, yes there are many here that know how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of small subs like:

```
Sub Greetings()
   With ActiveCell
      .Clear
      .Value = "Hello"
      .Font.Bold = True
   End With
End Sub
```

and assign them to the appropriate buttons.